# How to assign a role to an iam user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to assign a role to a user using the AWS console but not having a whole lot of success with it. So i created a user David and i created a role with a trust policy in which i am assigning the David i.e. IAM user as the principal which looks like this :-

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::Account-ID:user/David"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i also attached a policy to the role which lets the user `listbuckets` and `getobject`. The policy looks like this :-

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allowsusertotolistbuckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when i run `aws configure` and authenticate as David user with the right access key and secret access key and run `aws s3 ls`. I run into the following: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied`. How can i have the user assume the role. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have to attach your IAM Policy to the IAM User for your scenario. 

The over simplified concept (lot of exceptions apply) to remember is IAM Users is for Humans and IAM Role is for Systems. Also you might also need to work on your bucket policy to enable the the access to the IAM user.

Comment: @NaveenVijay You're right in the sense that i had to attach the policy but why can't i let the user assume the role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAM Roles are not 'attached' to a user. Rather, an IAM User **can be permitted to *assume* an IAM Role**.

Using the AWS CLI, they would assume an IAM Role like this:

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/xaccounts3access --role-session-name s3-access-example
```

In response, AWS STS will **return a set of temporary credentials:**

```json
{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROA3XFRBF535PLBIFPI4:s3-access-example",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/xaccounts3access/s3-access-example"
    },
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "9drTJvcXLB89EXAMPLELB8923FB892xMFI",
        "SessionToken": "AQoXdzELDDY//////////wEaoAK1wvxJY12r2IrDFT2IvAzTCn3zHoZ7YNtpiQLF0MqZye/qwjzP2iEXAMPLEbw/m3hsj8VBTkPORGvr9jM5sgP+w9IZWZnU+LWhmg+a5fDi2oTGUYcdg9uexQ4mtCHIHfi4citgqZTgco40Yqr4lIlo4V2b2Dyauk0eYFNebHtYlFVgAUj+7Indz3LU0aTWk1WKIjHmmMCIoTkyYp/k7kUG7moeEYKSitwQIi6Gjn+nyzM+PtoA3685ixzv0R7i5rjQi0YE0lf1oeie3bDiNHncmzosRM6SFiPzSvp6h/32xQuZsjcypmwsPSDtTPYcs0+YN/8BRi2/IcrxSpnWEXAMPLEXSDFTAQAM6Dl9zR0tXoybnlrZIwMLlMi1Kcgo5OytwU=",
        "Expiration": "2016-03-15T00:05:07Z",
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAJEXAMPLEXEG2JICEA"
    }
}
```

These credentials can then be used to call AWS service 'as the IAM Role' rather than 'as the IAM User'.

See: [assume-role — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html)

To make things easier, it is possible to **define a profile that uses an IAM Role**. The AWS CLI will automatically use IAM User credentials to call `AssumeRole()`, then use the resulting credentials to make the desired API call.

Here is an example profile entry:

```
[profile marketingadmin]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/marketingadminrole
source_profile = user1
```

This is saying: "Use the IAM User credentials from profile `user1` to call `AssumeRole()` on the `marketingadminrole`"

It can then be used like this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://marketing-bucket --profile marketingadmin
```

See: [Using an IAM role in the AWS CLI - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html)